# How to run external program from systemd service in independent cgroup

Tags: linux, systemd

I need to run external program from systemd service outside current cgroup.
I have found a `systemd-run` tool which would probably solve this but i'm stuck with systemd version 204 where it is not yet available.
Is there some other solution?

My problem in more detail:

Application is bundled in debian package and will install and run itself as systemd service.
This service later downloads newer version of application and runs `dpkg -i myapplication.deb`.
Service must be stopped during installation of upgrade - but it will not stop until all processes in cgroup ends. Now we have deadlock because `dpkg` is itself running in this cgroup. After service stopping timeout, `dpkg` is killed and upgrade is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your service dynamically in /run/systemd/system path. This path is the runtime service directory.

Later on you tell systemd to reload its state. Once the reload is done, now systemd knows about your service. Starting your service will happen in service's own cgroup.

I think you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "[Service]\nType=oneshot\nExecStart=dpkg -i myapplication.deb" \
> /run/systemd/system/my-dpkg.service
if [ -f "/run/systemd/system/my-dpkg.service" ]; then
    systemctl daemon-reload && \
    systemctl start dpkg.service
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pretty much any time you want to post code, or data that you would like to retain its formatting, you can indent it with four spaces (or a tab). # is markup shortcode for headings, so instead of `#!/bin/sh`, we saw !/bin/sh in larger text. You can do inline code with backticks (the apostrophe-looking thing next to the 1 key above QWERTY. So if I surround Hello World with ``, I get `Hello World`.